# How can we access archive messages into android application from xmpp server

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I took a brief overview on xmpp.org website, and read all things related to message archiving(XEP-0136 protocol). After reading all document, still i am not getting exact way to start implementation on that things into my android application.
Any one here can help me, how can we implement, accessing of message archive at client hand. I am using smack library for this in my application.

Comment: You probably want to use XEP-0313 these days, and not XEP-0136.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ensure that your server implements [XEP-0136](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html).  Many don't.

Next, you'll want to create your own subclass of IQ.  See [OfflineMessageRequest](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/offline/packet/OfflineMessageRequest.html) for an example.  You need getters and setters for all of the sub-elements of the archive protocol.

Penultimately, register your IQ handler with [ProviderManager.addIQProvider](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/provider/ProviderManager.html#addIQProvider%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Lastly, write a controller class that sends the IQs, waits for the results, and processes the semantics of the protocol.  See [OfflineMessageManager](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/offline/OfflineMessageManager.html) for a [XEP-0013](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html) example which is similar to what you want.

Comment: really thanks Joe.. your reply is really very helpful for me, and we already implement XEP-0136 accordingly at our server. Now i will try to implement accessing of message archiving as you suggest me at client side into my android application. If you can refer me any link or provide me code snipt also from where i will get exact way of logic to implement it in my code, so it is very benificial for me. I am looking positively for quick and positive reply from your side...once again thanks for replying.

Comment: hello Joe, i am trying according to your suggestion also, but still i am facing hard problems in exact implementation. Please can you share little bit code snippet with me. i am looking hopefully, please help me.

Comment: @sumeet - Try looking at this source since it is a fairly simple example http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/search?r=7071&r=9227&r=11613.  Depending on how complex your stanza parsing will be in your provider, you may also want to use the EmbeddedExtensionProvider http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk/source/org/jivesoftware/smackx/provider/EmbeddedExtensionProvider.java?hb=true

Comment: thanks Robin to share such a helpful link with me..now i am reading it...and will ask any query if i will face.

Comment: Hi Joe and Robin, i searched too much on this side, and not able to retrieve archived message from xmpp server..i read thoroughly all the apis available in smack library, but no one help me. If you can help me on the code snippet level, then may be that will help me to implement. please help me as quick as possible... i am totally frustrated from this implementation.

Comment: hi Joe....is any class available into smack library which is same as OfflineMessageManager and OfflineMessageRequest, and perform the job for message archiving in place of offline message.    please reply me quickly...

Comment: Please re-read the first point of my answer.  It's quite likely your server doesn't have XEP-0136 implemented or turned on.

Comment: OfflineMessageManager link is dead

Comment: @joao2fast4u I fixed the links.